# How to access url from prepareHeaders in redux toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

In order to add specific header, I need to check what the api/query url is. There isn't any param based on redux toolkit documentation.

```
export const gatewayApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'gatewayApi',
    tagTypes: [
        'Country',
        'Users',
    ],
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '/api/',
        prepareHeaders: headers => {
            headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
            const { auth } = JSON.parse(
            localStorage.getItem('user'),
            );

            const { accessToken } = JSON.parse(
             localStorage.getItem('token'),
            );

            const queryUrl = '**** TODO ****';

            if (isTokenAuth(queryUrl)) {
             headers.set('authorization', `${accessToken}`);
            } else if (auth) {
            headers.set('authorization', `${auth}`);
            }

            return headers;
        },
    }),
    endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can also just set headers from your endpoint's `query` function though:

```js
myEndpoint: build.query({
  query(arg) {
    return {
      url: ...,
      headers: { foo: "bar" }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to set header. Also need to check if specific header is set inside prepareHeaders with headers.get('authorization').

Comment: That should just work.